# How to set image size to display in Ipython.display?

Tags: python, ipython

How to set the image size to display? Running in VSCode Jupyter Interactive Window

```
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
display(Image.open('imageURL'))
```

This code displays the Image as it is, i.e showing the original size,

Tried this, which works, but how to keep the ratio, image shrunks as it is

```
image = Image.open('imageURL')
image = image.resize((500,500),Image.ANTIALIAS)
display(image)
```

Comment: Found the Answer from https://intellipaat.com/community/9926/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio, That works good

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
display(Image('image.png', width=600))
```

You can also set a `height`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
image = Image.open("imageURL")
scale = 0.3
display(image.resize(( int(image.width * scale), int(image.height * scale))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with video, you can do the following:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Video
display(Video(data=video_path, embed=True, width = 600, height = 300))
```

Note: It is not an answer to the image, but it is described as a reference.